# MPMediaItemArtwork and transparency

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, alpha, lockscreen, mpnowplayinginfocenter

While trying to obtain a transparent cover image on iPhone lock screen I got white background where it should be transparent.

Is it possible to use image with alpha channel for MPMediaItemArtwork at all? I found nothing about it in the [official docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMediaItemArtwork_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

[image]

Comment: Any update with this?

Comment: No, nothing. I've ended up using image with solid background.

Comment: yes I also changed image with solid background.

Comment: We also ended up using a solid background.

Answer (score 0):

The short and frustrating answer is *No* – it is not possible to set an `MPMediaItemArtwork` with transparency for iOS9 or earlier.

Comment: Still an issue with iOS 13, btw.